# SMB share: smbclient works, mount.cifs doesn't

Tags: mount

I have a Timecapsule with some USB drives attached to it. I can access it just fine from OSX. I can also access it via smbclient on my Raspberry Pi:

```
smbclient -U foobar //192.168.1.1/drive                                                                             
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter foobar's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Apple Base Station] Server=[CIFS 4.32]
smb: \> ls
  .                                   D        0  Tue Feb 12 20:36:00 2019
  ..                                  D        0  Tue Dec 25 19:15:36 2018
  .com.apple.timemachine.supported      H        0  Tue Dec 12 19:26:41 2017
  .DS_Store                           H     6148  Mon Jun 10 11:43:11 2019

                156198988 blocks of size 4096. 129774214 blocks available
```

But when I try to mount it via mount.cifs, I always get a file not found:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/drive /media/drive -o username=foobar,password=somepass,sec=ntlm,uid=pi,vers=1.0 --verbose

mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.1,unc=\\192.168.1.1\drive,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0,uid=1000,user=foobar,pass=********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The mount point exists, I tried other mount points as well. Now I am at the end of my wits. Any ideas why I get this message?

Comment: Using *smb* has noting to do with Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel slightly stupid: the Pi had some uptime and turns out the kernel had been updated, but the modules would not fit unless I reboot. After a reboot cifs would work just fine.